# Criar variável dinamicamente

Tags: javascript

Tenho um ciclo `for`, e queria criar uma variável dinamicamente, para não voltar a repetir código em JavaScript. Utilizei o `eval`, mas não funciona. Exemplo:

```
for (var y = 1; y <= 2; y++) {
    eval('var max_arr' + y + ' = Math.max.apply(Math, this["arr_valeur" + y];');
}
```

ou isto:

```
var max_arr+y = Math.max.apply(Math, this["arr_valeur"+y]);
```

Comment: Não é mais fácil usar um _array_? E seria melhor você acrescentar na pergunta o resultado que quer obter, e não apenas como está tentando resolver. E qual seria a vantagem de aplicar max num ítem só?

Comment: como posso usar o array? O resultado que quero obter é o valor maximo de outro array.

Comment: O loop é para utilizar a variavel 2 vezes com o seu nome diferente. Ou seja max_arr1 e max_arr2.

Comment: Acrescentei um exemplo para facilitar o entendimento.

Comment: Definitivamente não consigo entender o motivo de tantos votos contra a pergunta...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você deve usar *arrays* dentro de *arrays* para isto, e não `eval`.

Sintaxe:

```
for(var y = 1; y <= 2; y++ ) {
   max_arr[y] = Math.max.apply( null, arr_valeur[y] );
}
```

### Exemplo:

```js
var arr_valeur = [];
var plus_grand = [];

arr_valeur[1] = [ 112,   1, 389 ];
arr_valeur[2] = [  44,  42,  30 ];

for ( var y = 1; y <= 2; y++) {
  plus_grand[y] = Math.max.apply(null, arr_valeur[y]);
}

document.body.innerHTML += plus_grand[1] + '<br>';
document.body.innerHTML += plus_grand[2] + '<br>';
```

### Usando eval:

> Não use esta versão! Acrescentei este código só para você entender a sintaxe correta do que tentou fazer inicialmente.

Não inspira nenhuma confiança um código destes em uso. Funciona, mas o *array* existe para ser usado. Isto aqui é gambiarra, e é sinal de conhecimento insuficiente da linguagem:

```js
var arr_valeur1 = [ 112,   1, 389 ];
var arr_valeur2 = [  44,  42,  30 ];

for ( var y = 1; y <= 2; y++) {
   eval( 'var max_arr' + y + ' = Math.max.apply(null, arr_valeur' + y + ');' );
}

document.body.innerHTML += max_arr1 + '<br>';
document.body.innerHTML += max_arr2 + '<br>';
```