# Criar variaveis dinâmicas em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, variáveis

Quando eu estou em PHP e tem variáveis dinâmicas, ex: `nomeVariavel1`,`nomeVariavel2`, `nomeVariavel3`, utilizo da seguinte maneira para colocar no banco:

```
$nomeVariavel = ${"nomeVarivavel".$contador}
```

Como posso fazer exatamente isso em JavaScript? Passando como parâmetro ou de uma outra forma?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Criar variável dinamicamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46177/criar-vari%c3%a1vel-dinamicamente)

Comment: Possível duplicata de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122604/como-criar-uma-variavel-din%C3%A2mica

Comment: Até acho que pode ter uma duplicata mas não acho que estas sejam, pelo menos não para algo tão simples.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade o que você deseja nem é isto é o bom é velho *array*.

```js
var nomeVariavel = [1, 2, 3];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) console.log(nomeVariavel[i]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Basic.js).

Se está fazendo em PHP do jeito postado está fazendo muito errado. E lá funciona igual ao JavaScript, é só usar um *array*.

Comment: Na verdade eu preciso fechar janelas criadas com window.open, entao var mywindow = window.open(...) . Depois preciso pegar essa variavel como parametro. E uma variavel , se eu passar funcao("mywindow"). esse parametro nao podera fazer um mywindow.close() , obvio. Queria uma forma de fazer isso

Comment: A sua pergunta não fala sobre, eu respondi sobre o que perguntou.

Comment: @RodrigoLuan basta passar a referência direta de `mywindow` como parâmetro. Passar uma *string* e querer acessar a variável da *string* não faz sentido algum neste caso. Como o bigown disse: está fazendo muito errado.

Answer (score 0):

Podes. No entanto tens que te lembrar que todas as variaveis sem contexto, isto é todas as variaveis que nao sejam declaradas num objecto, são do contexto `window`;

Então,

```
   var a = 1;
```

é o mesmo que

```
window.a = 1;
```

então,

```
window.a = "hello world"
var nomeDaVariavel = "a";
alert(window[nomeDaVariavel]) // "hello world"
```

em ES6 o seguinte também é possivel:

```
let a = {[nomeDaVariavel]: "not hello world"};
console.log(a) // {"a": "not hello world"}
```